# Как задать картинку в DataGrid в определенном случае

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть код, в котором выводятся некоторые данные в таблицу

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;

namespace Students_Book_3._0
{

public partial class prepodupravPE : Window
{

    public prepodupravPE()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    class MyTable
    {
        public MyTable(int ID, string ФИО,string Фото, string Специфик, string Группа)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.ФИО = ФИО;
            this.Фото = Фото;

            this.Специфик = Специфик;

            this.Группа = Группа;


        }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ФИО { get; set; }
        public string Фото { get; set; }

        public string Специфик { get; set; }

        public string Группа { get; set; }


    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<MyTable> result = new List<MyTable>(100000);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("declor/ConfigurationS.sb");
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
        {

            int Id1 = int.Parse(node.Attributes[0].Value);
            string id = node["id"].InnerText;
            string fio1 = node["fio"].InnerText;

            string date1 = node["date"].InnerText;


            string spec1 = node["specification1"].InnerText;
            string group1 = node["group1"].InnerText;



            result.Add(new MyTable(Id1, fio1, id, spec1, group1));

        }
        grid.ItemsSource = result;
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void grid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Вот так это это выглядит в XML

```
<Window x:Class="Students_Book_3._0.prepodupravPE"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Students_Book_3._0"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="prepodupravPE" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="2edf92257a2dd443c7ec2f29e1df3d6e.jpg"/>
</Window.Background>
<Grid>
    <Viewbox  MaxHeight="2500" Margin="-10,0,10,-8">

        <Canvas Width="604" Height="317">
            <ComboBox Canvas.Left="10" Width="120" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="grid" Height="285" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="22" Width="313" Opacity="0.7" Foreground="Black" Background="Black" SelectionChanged="grid_SelectionChanged" FontSize="10"/>
            <Button Content="Поиск" Canvas.Left="130" Width="75" Height="22"/>
            <Button Content="Добавить" Canvas.Left="248" Width="75" Height="22"/>

        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Файл ConfigurationS.sb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<students>
<student id="1">
<id>1</id>
<fio>Крейзив Данила Тычоевич</fio>
<name>Данила</name>
<otch>Тычоевич</otch>
<fam>Крейзив</fam>
<date>16.10.2007</date>
<vozr>12</vozr>
<specification1>EV3</specification1>
<group1>КМ-02</group1>
<specification2>EV3</specification2>
<group2>КМ-01</group2>
<specification3>
</specification3>
<group3>
</group3>
<specification4>
</specification4>
<group4>
</group4>
<specification5>
</specification5>
<group5>
</group5>
<specification6>
</specification6>
<group6>
</group6>
<specification7>
</specification7>
<group7>
</group7>
<specification8>
</specification8>
<group8>
</group8>
<balance1>320</balance1>
<colvozanat1>0</colvozanat1>
<balance2>280</balance2>
<colvozanat2>0</colvozanat2>
<balance3>0</balance3>
<colvozanat3>0</colvozanat3>
<balance4>0</balance4>
<colvozanat4>0</colvozanat4>
<balance5>0</balance5>
<colvozanat5>0</colvozanat5>
<balance6>0</balance6>
<colvozanat6>0</colvozanat6>
<balance7>0</balance7>
<colvozanat7>0</colvozanat7>
<balance8>0</balance8>
<colvozanat8>0</colvozanat8>
<posesh1>14</posesh1>
<posesh2>0</posesh2>
<posesh3>0</posesh3>
<posesh4>0</posesh4>
<posesh5>0</posesh5>
<posesh6>0</posesh6>
<posesh7>0</posesh7>
<posesh8>0</posesh8>
<oplata1>10</oplata1>
<oplata2>15</oplata2>
<oplata3>0</oplata3>
<oplata4>0</oplata4>
<oplata5>0</oplata5>
<oplata6>0</oplata6>
<oplata7>0</oplata7>
<oplata8>0</oplata8>
<school>0</school>
<bally1>0</bally1>
<bally2>0</bally2>
<bally3>0</bally3>
<bally4>0</bally4>
<bally5>0</bally5>
<bally6>0</bally6>
<bally7>0</bally7>
<bally8>0</bally8>
<id>1</id>
<prepod>Качалов Сергей Олегович</prepod>
<regdate>29.01.2020</regdate>
<status>Активен</status>
<skidos>0</skidos>
<parent1>Маман</parent1>
<parentname1>Пох Че Тут</parentname1>
<parentphone1>88001006868</parentphone1>
<parent2>Папан</parent2>
<parentname2>Пох Че Тут</parentname2>
<parentphone2>88001007575</parentphone2>
<parent3>Бабан</parent3>
<parentname3>Пох Че Тут</parentname3>
<parentphone3>88001008383</parentphone3>
<parent4>Дедан</parent4>
<parentname4>Пох Че Тут</parentname4>
<parentphone4>88001002727</parentphone4>
<parent5>Бабан</parent5>
<parentname5>Пох Че Тут</parentname5>
<parentphone5>88001003939</parentphone5>
<parent6>Дедан</parent6>
<parentname6>Вин Ни Пух</parentname6>
<parentphone6>88001001010</parentphone6>
<lastcheng>88001001010</lastcheng>
<nachalo1>00:00:00</nachalo1>
<Konec1>00:00:00</Konec1>
<time1>00:00:00</time1>
<obshtime1>00:00:00</obshtime1>
<babkizachas1>0</babkizachas1>
<nachalo2>00:00:00</nachalo2>
<Konec2>00:00:00</Konec2>
<time2>00:00:00</time2>
<obshtime2>00:00:00</obshtime2>
<babkizachas2>0</babkizachas2>
<nachalo3>00:00:00</nachalo3>
<Konec3>00:00:00</Konec3>
<time3>00:00:00</time3>
<obshtime3>00:00:00</obshtime3>
<babkizachas3>0</babkizachas3>
<nachalo4>00:00:00</nachalo4>
<Konec4>00:00:00</Konec4>
<time4>00:00:00</time4>
<obshtime4>00:00:00</obshtime4>
<babkizachas4>0</babkizachas4>
<nachalo5>00:00:00</nachalo5>
<Konec5>00:00:00</Konec5>
<time5>00:00:00</time5>
<obshtime5>00:00:00</obshtime5>
<babkizachas5>0</babkizachas5>
<nachalo6>00:00:00</nachalo6>
<Konec6>00:00:00</Konec6>
<time6>00:00:00</time6>
<obshtime6>00:00:00</obshtime6>
<babkizachas6>0</babkizachas6>
<nachalo7>00:00:00</nachalo7>
<Konec7>00:00:00</Konec7>
<time7>00:00:00</time7>
<obshtime7>00:00:00</obshtime7>
<babkizachas7>0</babkizachas7>
<nachalo8>00:00:00</nachalo8>
<Konec8>00:00:00</Konec8>
<time8>00:00:00</time8>
<obshtime8>00:00:00</obshtime8>
<babkizachas8>0</babkizachas8>
<dolg1>10</dolg1>
<dolg2>0</dolg2>
<dolg3>0</dolg3>
<dolg4>0</dolg4>
<dolg5>0</dolg5>
<dolg6>0</dolg6>
<dolg7>0</dolg7>
<dolg8>0</dolg8>
<zapas1>30</zapas1>
<zapas2>0</zapas2>
<zapas3>0</zapas3>
<zapas4>0</zapas4>
<zapas5>0</zapas5>
<zapas6>0</zapas6>
<zapas7>0</zapas7>
<zapas8>0</zapas8>
<dat1></dat1>
<dat2></dat2>
<dat3></dat3>
<dat4></dat4>
<dat5></dat5>
<dat6></dat6>
<dat7></dat7>
<dat8></dat8>
</student>
<student id="2">
<id>2</id>
<fio>111 2222 333333</fio>
<name>111</name>
<otch>333333</otch>
<fam>2222</fam>
<date>15.10.2007</date>
<vozr>12</vozr>
<specification1>EV3</specification1>
<group1>КМ-03</group1>
<specification2>WeDo</specification2>
<group2>КВ-01</group2>
<specification3>
</specification3>
<group3>
</group3>
<specification4>
</specification4>
<group4>
</group4>
<specification5>
</specification5>
<group5>
</group5>
<specification6>
</specification6>
<group6>
</group6>
<specification7>
</specification7>
<group7>
</group7>
<specification8>
</specification8>
<group8>
</group8>
<balance1>0</balance1>
<colvozanat1>0</colvozanat1>
<balance2>0</balance2>
<colvozanat2>0</colvozanat2>
<balance3>0</balance3>
<colvozanat3>0</colvozanat3>
<balance4>0</balance4>
<colvozanat4>0</colvozanat4>
<balance5>0</balance5>
<colvozanat5>0</colvozanat5>
<balance6>0</balance6>
<colvozanat6>0</colvozanat6>
<balance7>0</balance7>
<colvozanat7>0</colvozanat7>
<balance8>0</balance8>
<colvozanat8>0</colvozanat8>
<posesh1>14</posesh1>
<posesh2>0</posesh2>
<posesh3>0</posesh3>
<posesh4>0</posesh4>
<posesh5>0</posesh5>
<posesh6>0</posesh6>
<posesh7>0</posesh7>
<posesh8>0</posesh8>
<oplata1>0</oplata1>
<oplata2>0</oplata2>
<oplata3>0</oplata3>
<oplata4>0</oplata4>
<oplata5>0</oplata5>
<oplata6>0</oplata6>
<oplata7>0</oplata7>
<oplata8>0</oplata8>
<school>0</school>
<bally1>0</bally1>
<bally2>0</bally2>
<bally3>0</bally3>
<bally4>0</bally4>
<bally5>0</bally5>
<bally6>0</bally6>
<bally7>0</bally7>
<bally8>0</bally8>
<id>2</id>
<prepod>Качалов Сергей Олегович</prepod>
<regdate>29.01.2020</regdate>
<status>Активен</status>
<skidos>0</skidos>
<parent1>Маман</parent1>
<parentname1>Пох Че Тут</parentname1>
<parentphone1>88001006868</parentphone1>
<parent2>Папан</parent2>
<parentname2>Пох Че Тут</parentname2>
<parentphone2>88001007575</parentphone2>
<parent3>Бабан</parent3>
<parentname3>Пох Че Тут</parentname3>
<parentphone3>88001008383</parentphone3>
<parent4>Дедан</parent4>
<parentname4>Пох Че Тут</parentname4>
<parentphone4>88001002727</parentphone4>
<parent5>Бабан</parent5>
<parentname5>Пох Че Тут</parentname5>
<parentphone5>88001003939</parentphone5>
<parent6>Дедан</parent6>
<parentname6>Вин Ни Пух</parentname6>
<parentphone6>88001001010</parentphone6>
<lastcheng>88001001010</lastcheng>
<nachalo1>00:00:00</nachalo1>
<Konec1>00:00:00</Konec1>
<time1>00:00:00</time1>
<obshtime1>00:00:00</obshtime1>
<babkizachas1>0</babkizachas1>
<nachalo2>00:00:00</nachalo2>
<Konec2>00:00:00</Konec2>
<time2>00:00:00</time2>
<obshtime2>00:00:00</obshtime2>
<babkizachas2>0</babkizachas2>
<nachalo3>00:00:00</nachalo3>
<Konec3>00:00:00</Konec3>
<time3>00:00:00</time3>
<obshtime3>00:00:00</obshtime3>
<babkizachas3>0</babkizachas3>
<nachalo4>00:00:00</nachalo4>
<Konec4>00:00:00</Konec4>
<time4>00:00:00</time4>
<obshtime4>00:00:00</obshtime4>
<babkizachas4>0</babkizachas4>
<nachalo5>00:00:00</nachalo5>
<Konec5>00:00:00</Konec5>
<time5>00:00:00</time5>
<obshtime5>00:00:00</obshtime5>
<babkizachas5>0</babkizachas5>
<nachalo6>00:00:00</nachalo6>
<Konec6>00:00:00</Konec6>
<time6>00:00:00</time6>
<obshtime6>00:00:00</obshtime6>
<babkizachas6>0</babkizachas6>
<nachalo7>00:00:00</nachalo7>
<Konec7>00:00:00</Konec7>
<time7>00:00:00</time7>
<obshtime7>00:00:00</obshtime7>
<babkizachas7>0</babkizachas7>
<nachalo8>00:00:00</nachalo8>
<Konec8>00:00:00</Konec8>
<time8>00:00:00</time8>
<obshtime8>00:00:00</obshtime8>
<babkizachas8>0</babkizachas8>
<dolg1>0</dolg1>
<dolg2>0</dolg2>
<dolg3>0</dolg3>
<dolg4>0</dolg4>
<dolg5>0</dolg5>
<dolg6>0</dolg6>
<dolg7>0</dolg7>
<dolg8>0</dolg8>
<zapas1>0</zapas1>
<zapas2>0</zapas2>
<zapas3>0</zapas3>
<zapas4>0</zapas4>
<zapas5>0</zapas5>
<zapas6>0</zapas6>
<zapas7>0</zapas7>
<zapas8>0</zapas8>
<dat1></dat1>
<dat2></dat2>
<dat3></dat3>
<dat4></dat4>
<dat5></dat5>
<dat6></dat6>
<dat7></dat7>
<dat8></dat8>
</student>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы вместо "id" (ИМЕННО НЕ Id1(по коду, в таблице указанно как "Фото") !!!) выводилась картинка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста xaml разметку для `DataGrid`

Comment: И как-то странно вы парсите xml, его тоже покажите пожалуйста. Хотя-бы для пары строк, имена можно заменить на вымышленные.

Comment: Если очень кратко, то 1) вам нужна колонка `DataGridTemplateColumn`, в шаблоне которой есть `Image`, `Source` которой привязан к строке, содержащей путь к картинке. 2) А xml можно парсить без цикла и одной строчкой кода, подготовив при этом правильно класс для данных. 3) И что за List 100000? Вы выделяете память под 100000 записей? Зачем? Это же `List` а не массив, просто уберите число.

Comment: @aepot, я могу показать, без проблем, но какой смысл? там полностью пусто. все управление через C#

Comment: Если я спрашиваю, значит смысл есть. :) Окей, покажите, как вы создаете `DataGrid` в интерфейсе и все другие контролы, которые там есть. И вы меня пугаете.

Comment: @aepot, благодарю за подробный ответ, но к сожалению я ничего не понял. я не так хорошо разбираюсь в коде что бы понимать написанное

Comment: @aepot мне выложить в вопросе или лучше в лс?

Comment: Давайте всё в вопрос, чем больше я узнаю, тем качественнее будет ответ.

Comment: @aepot, добавил xml в вопрос

Comment: Ещё xml `ConfigurationS.sb` с данными, если вы хотите, чтобы я вам помог упростить код их загрузки. Не весь, хотя-бы для пары строк таблицы с вымышленными именами, для тестирования кода он в любом случае пригодится.

Comment: @aepot, добавил файл

Comment: Всё забрал, разбираюсь, но от ненормативной лексики в файле я бы избавился в вопросе, все-таки это публичный сайт. Чуть позже оформлю ответ.

Comment: @aepot, да. по по поводу лексики моя вина. не проследил. я так для всех тестов делал но без фанатизма. .....что касаемо остального, огромное спасибо, жду ответа